# Visual Studio Ripple Error DEP10401

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, ripple

im develop a hybrid app with the ionic framework and visual studio 2015. This afternoon everything works great. But suddenly my ripple emulator dont work anymore.  I get the following error:

> DEP10401 : The Ripple emulator requires Google Chrome to launch your app . Chrome is not installed on this computer . Please install Chrome : " https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html " .

But I have Chrome installed. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is appeared because Visual Studio was not recognize Chrome registry key.

Registry default key value is changed "Google Chrome" to "Chrome", when Google Chrome updated.

Therefore you just change registry value.

[Solution]

1. Run "regedit"
2. Go to path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome"
3. Change default value "Chrome" to "Google Chrome"
4. Try again build.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into the same problem when moving my VS2015 dev environment from the default Administrator account to a standard user account.   I had cloned the administrator's 'User' folder to  my new user, but not the registry hive.

In my case Chrome was using per-user settings, and the problem was resolved by setting up the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome key using the following reg file.  You need to replace *?MyUserName?*  with your user's folder name.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome]
@="Google Chrome"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="Google Chrome is a web browser that runs web pages and applications with lightning speed. It's fast, stable and easy to use. Browse the web more safely with malware and phishing protection built into Google Chrome."
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Google Chrome"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".htm"="ChromeHTML"
".html"="ChromeHTML"
".shtml"="ChromeHTML"
".xht"="ChromeHTML"
".xhtml"="ChromeHTML"
".webp"="ChromeHTML"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities\Startmenu]
"StartMenuInternet"="Google Chrome"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"ftp"="ChromeHTML"
"http"="ChromeHTML"
"https"="ChromeHTML"
"irc"="ChromeHTML"
"mailto"="ChromeHTML"
"mms"="ChromeHTML"
"news"="ChromeHTML"
"nntp"="ChromeHTML"
"sms"="ChromeHTML"
"smsto"="ChromeHTML"
"tel"="ChromeHTML"
"urn"="ChromeHTML"
"webcal"="ChromeHTML"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\InstallInfo]
"ReinstallCommand"="\"C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --make-default-browser"
"HideIconsCommand"="\"C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --hide-icons"
"ShowIconsCommand"="\"C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --show-icons"
"IconsVisible"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\?MyUserName?\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\""
```